# better site analytics service / script: real time statistics and time spent on pages?

Tags: analytics, statistics

I'm looking for a site analytics software (service or script) that must be easy to comprehend. GA is simply too much complicated and it misses some key features (for me).

Missing features are:

- real time statistics (very important)
- time spent on page (very important)

about the "time spent on page"... i do really need a statistics software that does not calculate the time between two page views.

this is not useful at all in my case. because i mostly do 1 pageview = 1 user

but something that logs, for example, every 10 seconds spent on a page

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

On Google Analytics you can go on the tab called "Home", then go to "Real time", and "Overview" for real time analytics.
For time spent, i usually look at AW stats, which is not great, but apparently does the job.
Just in canse you didn't know about the real time option on ga.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mint  haveamint.com  it might do what you're looking for.